# how to find index by value in ChunkedArray from Apache Arrow?

Tags: apache-arrow

The closest I can find seems to be the `index` from ComputeFunction:

https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/api/compute.html

But I do not find a working code example for it in C++ from the apache arrow codebase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the documentation for that function in the cpp docs:

```
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/cpp/compute.html#aggregations
```

And here's a short example of how to call the function in C++:

```
8.0.0: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/apache-arrow-8.0.0/cpp/src/arrow/compute/kernels/aggregate_test.cc#L2234

7.0.0: https://github.com/apache/arrow/blob/apache-arrow-7.0.0/cpp/src/arrow/compute/kernels/aggregate_test.cc#L2206
```

---

[2022-05-23 Edit]

Here is an example that calls the `Index` function, using arrow 7.0.0:

```
https://github.com/drin/cookbooks/blob/mainline/arrow/compute-api/recipe.cpp#L18
```

The `recipe.hpp` file should show the required includes and types that are used (I tried to minimize to just what's necessary).

Also, here is corresponding code for usage, including making some test data and using the `IndexOf` function and viewing the result:

```
https://github.com/drin/cookbooks/blob/mainline/arrow/compute-api/index.cpp#L18
```

I wrote `IndexOf` to show how you can use the `Index` function yourself, so you can use it directly, or write a wrapper function in a similar style.

NOTE: I thought I needed to upgrade to 8.0.0 to use `Scalar` types, but I think 8.0.0 mostly introduced the documentation for `Scalar` rather than introducing code for it, as this works with arrow 7.0.0.